# std::sort a class that's implemented a move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdvector, move-semantics

Is it possible to use std::sort without using the whole element?

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, myclass> > unsorted_vec;
for (some_iterations) {
    unsorted_vec.emplace_back(rand(), std::move(instance_of_myclass));
}
std::sort(unsorted_vec.begin(), unsorted_vec.end(), 
          [](auto & l, auto & r) { return l.first < r.first; });
```

The above code gives the following compilation bug unless the `std::sort` line is commented out.

```
error: use of deleted function 'myclass & myclass::operator=(const myclass &)' is 
       implicitly declared as delete because 'myclass' declares a move constructor.
```

Now I did declare a move constructor for myclass, and furthermore, I actually want the reference constructor deleted. My question is, how do I sort this array? Is it possible to get a reference to the first part of my pair without touching the second part?

Comment: What is `myclass`?

Comment: Did you create a *move assignment operator* for `myclass`?

Comment: The issue is not about accessing one member of the pair but not the other.The issue is that sorting moves items around, but your object isn't move-assignable.

Comment: @Galik `myclass` is a big hunking class full of data and unique_ptrs. I created a *move constructor* for `myclass` but not a *move assignment operator*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this reference on [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) your class needs to be both *move constructable* and *move assignable* in order to be *sortable*.

If your class is not inherently *moveble* then something like this should work fine:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass(myclass const&) = delete; // or implement
    myclass(myclass&& other) { /* stuff to construct */ }

    myclass& operator=(myclass const&) = delete; // or implement
    myclass& operator=(myclass&& other) { /* stuff to assign */ return *this; }

};
```